# Multiple spinners without the use of multiple functions

Tags: css, ajax, jquery

I am using a loading icon for my Ajax functions as follows :

```
div id='loader' style="display: none;" align="right">
     <img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>


complete: function(){
    $('#loader').hide();
},
beforeSend: function(data) { 

    $('#loader').show();
 },
```

However If I want to have multiple spinners on the same page I will normally needs to have many divs e.g

```
div id='loader2' style="display: none;" align="right">
    <img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
div id='loader3' style="display: none;" align="right">
    <img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
```

etc ..

Is there a way to do this somewhat dynamically so I don't have to define every each of them ?

Comment: You can easily set the image src attribute to whatever you want. The question is, how do you want to change it? Randomly, from a set list of images or what?

Comment: Please select an answer if you've found one to be correct or helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than targeting by ID, you can just look for .loader within some unique HTML scope. For example:

```
complete: function(){
  $(this).parents('.some-class').find('.loader').hide();
},

beforeSend: function(data) {
  $(this).parents('.some-class').find('.loader').show();
},
```

Comment: Thanks I have ended up doing it using the class id e.g $(".someclass").find('#loader').show();

Comment: Good, except you might say "class name", not "class ID", which is confusing. If you found my answer useful, please mark it accepted.